# ¿Como puedo obtener de una hora ingresada por el usuario en un DateTimePicker en visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, date, datetime, data

Necesito ingresar una hora en un datetimepicker y que el sistema tome esa hora que ingrese y me la muestre, ahorita solo me esta mostrando la hora del sistema

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask],y no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio,  saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes personalizar el formato de DateTimePicker [Véase aquí cómo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_DateTimePicker_CustomFormat)

```
Public Sub MiFormato()
    ' Por ejemplo 15/06/2021 12:00 PM, formato dia y hora 
    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy hh':'mm tt"
End Sub
```

Si solamente te interesa la hora:

```
    Public Sub MiFormato()
    ' Por ejemplo 12:00:05, formato  hora:
    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "hh':'mm':'ss"
End Sub
```